# Wrap whole column if one row doesn't fit

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to wrap all my `.row-value` divs once one of them doesn't fit into a single row with the `.row-label`. As you can see on the screenshot below the Vehicle label wrapped nicely but what I want to see is the other 2 also wrapping at the same time if the longest doesn't fit.

I've been googling and spent a few hours myself trying to solve it... without any real progress. I have tried tables and column blocks (which don't quite work because they keep my values away from the labels).

[image]

Ideally I want to achieve this

[image]

Could you point me in the right direction? I'm really stuck.

```css
.wrapping-table {
  width: 50%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.row-label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.row-value {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapping-table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row-label">Type</div>
    <div class="row-value">This is a really long text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row-label">Name</div>
    <div class="row-value">Short name</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row-label">Vehicle</div>
    <div class="row-value">Vehicle with a really really long name</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to know which one is the longest one?

Comment: This is not possible with CSS. You need Javascript or use media-queries,

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery it worked for me. Check if this is what you want.
I used some of @Sumit Patel code.

jquery

```
$('.row-value').each(function() {
  var content = $(this).width();
  var sibling = $(this).prev('.row-label').width();
  var row = $(this).parent('.row').width();

  if((content+sibling)>row){
     $('.row-value').addClass("wrap");
     return false;
  }

});
```

css

```
.wrapping-table {
  width: 50%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.row-label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.row-value {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.wrap {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use jquery to achieve this check snippet. after certain work you can add class and then wrap it.

```js
var showChar = 100;
$('.row-value').each(function() {
  var content = $(this).html();

  if (content.length > showChar) {

    $(this).addClass("wrap");

  }

});
```

```css
.wrapping-table {
  width: 50%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.row-label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.row-value {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.wrap {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapping-table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row-label">Type</div>
    <div class="row-value">This is a really long text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row-label">Name</div>
    <div class="row-value">Short name</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row-label">Vehicle</div>
    <div class="row-value">Vehicle with a really fgdfg sdfgsfgdreally lonfgfg sfdg sfg name</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I know when it wraps? When the values have enough space, they should be on a single row. PS: wasn't me downvoting it.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk if you haven't then dont worry that one who did has to add the comment to help other.

Comment: Close but this does not quite match the required result. Additional styling or the `row-label` would be required to force a line breal. Also you seem to be using a "magic" number.